# How to make open modal when click link in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I want create a modal popup. I created CSS for its style and finally it is completed but as I'm not familiar with JQuery or JavaScript I am not able to create a function that animates and opens the modal on click of a button or a link.
I also searched on Google but what is the benefit when I don't know how I add it with jQuery to open?

So, I request to any jQuery specialist to help me to add jQuery so that when user click on links or buttons it will open in animated method.

**Code**

```css
/*
    ColorBox Core Style:
    The following CSS is consistent between example themes and should not be altered.
*/
#colorbox {
 width:700px!important; height:600px!important;
}
#colorbox, #cboxOverlay, #cboxWrapper{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:9999; overflow:hidden;}
#cboxOverlay{position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%;}
#cboxMiddleLeft, #cboxBottomLeft{clear:left;}
#cboxContent{position:relative;}
#cboxLoadedContent{overflow:auto;}
#cboxTitle{margin:0;}
#cboxLoadingOverlay, #cboxLoadingGraphic{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%;}
#cboxPrevious, #cboxNext, #cboxClose, #cboxSlideshow{cursor:pointer;}
.cboxPhoto{float:left; margin:auto; border:0; display:block;}
.cboxIframe{width:100%; height:100%; display:block; border:0;}

/* 
    User Style:
    Change the following styles to modify the appearance of ColorBox.  They are
    ordered & tabbed in a way that represents the nesting of the generated HTML.
*/


#cboxOverlay{background:#fff;}
#colorbox{}
    #cboxTopLeft{width:25px; height:25px; background:url(https://easy.itzcash.com/Itzcasheasy/Images/border1.png) no-repeat 0 0;}
    #cboxTopCenter{height:25px; background:url(https://easy.itzcash.com/Itzcasheasy/Images/border1.png) repeat-x 0 -50px;}
    #cboxTopRight{width:25px; height:25px; background:url(https://easy.itzcash.com/Itzcasheasy/Images/border1.png) no-repeat -25px 0;}
    #cboxBottomLeft{width:25px; height:25px; background:url(https://easy.itzcash.com/Itzcasheasy/Images/border1.png) no-repeat 0 -25px;}
    #cboxBottomCenter{height:25px; background:url(https://easy.itzcash.com/Itzcasheasy/Images/border1.png) repeat-x 0 -75px;}
    #cboxBottomRight{width:25px; height:25px; background:url(https://easy.itzcash.com/Itzcasheasy/Images/border1.png) no-repeat -25px -25px;}
    #cboxMiddleLeft{width:25px; background:url(https://easy.itzcash.com/Itzcasheasy/Images/border2.png) repeat-y 0 0;}
    #cboxMiddleRight{width:25px; background:url(https://easy.itzcash.com/Itzcasheasy/Images/border2.png) repeat-y -25px 0;}
    #cboxContent{background:#fff; overflow:hidden;}
        .cboxIframe{background:#fff;}
        #cboxError{padding:50px; border:1px solid #ccc;}
        #cboxLoadedContent{margin-bottom:20px;}
        #cboxTitle{position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:0; text-align:center; width:100%; color:#999;}
        #cboxCurrent{position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:100px; color:#999;}
        #cboxSlideshow{position:absolute; bottom:0px; right:42px; color:#444;}
        #cboxPrevious{position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:0; color:#444;}
        #cboxNext{position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:63px; color:#444;}
        #cboxLoadingOverlay{background:#fff url(https://easy.itzcash.com/Itzcasheasy/Images/loading.gif) no-repeat 5px 5px;}
        #cboxClose{position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0; display:block; color:#444;}

/*
  The following fixes a problem where IE7 and IE8 replace a PNG's alpha transparency with a black fill
  when an alpha filter (opacity change) is set on the element or ancestor element.  This style is not applied to or needed in IE9.
  See: http://jacklmoore.com/notes/ie-transparency-problems/
*/
.cboxIE #cboxTopLeft,
.cboxIE #cboxTopCenter,
.cboxIE #cboxTopRight,
.cboxIE #cboxBottomLeft,
.cboxIE #cboxBottomCenter,
.cboxIE #cboxBottomRight,
.cboxIE #cboxMiddleLeft,
.cboxIE #cboxMiddleRight {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF);
}
```

```html
<div id="cboxOverlay" autocomplete="off" style="opacity: 0.9; cursor: pointer; display: block;"></div>

<div id="colorbox" class="" autocomplete="off" style="padding-bottom: 50px; padding-right: 50px; display: block; top: 0px; left: 375px; position: absolute; width: 550px; height: 306px; opacity: 1; cursor: auto; overflow: hidden;"><div id="cboxWrapper" autocomplete="off" style="height: 356px; width: 600px;"><div><div id="cboxTopLeft" autocomplete="off" style="float: left;"></div><div id="cboxTopCenter" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; width: 550px;"></div><div id="cboxTopRight" autocomplete="off" style="float: left;"></div></div><div style="clear: left;"><div id="cboxMiddleLeft" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; height: 306px;"></div><div id="cboxContent" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; width: 550px; height: 306px;"><div id="cboxLoadedContent" style="width: 550px; overflow: auto; height: 286px;"><div id="inline_content" style="background: #fff;" autocomplete="off">
  <h3 class="page-title_fg">Forget Password</h3>
  <form style="padding: 15px;">
   <label>User Name*</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="fuserName" name="fuserName" class="box" maxlength="15" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off"><br>
   <label>Date of Birth*</label> <input type="text" id="fdob" name="fdob" class="box" maxlength="15" autofocus="autofocus" onclick="clkdate('fdob');" readonly="readonly" autocomplete="off"><br> 
   <label>Email id*</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="femailId" name="femailId" class="box" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off"><br>
   <!-- <input type="button" value="Get Password" id="forget_pwd_submit_btn" class="login_btn"/>
   <input type="button" value="Reset" id="forget_pwd_reset_btn" class="login_btn"/> -->
   <button type="button" value="Get Password" id="forget_pwd_submit_btn" autocomplete="off">Get Password</button>
   <button type="button" value="Reset" id="forget_pwd_reset_btn" autocomplete="off">Reset</button>
  </form>
 </div></div><div id="cboxLoadingOverlay" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; height: 306px; display: none;"></div><div id="cboxLoadingGraphic" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; height: 306px; display: none;"></div><div id="cboxTitle" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; display: block;"></div><div id="cboxCurrent" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; display: none;"></div><div id="cboxNext" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; display: none;"></div><div id="cboxPrevious" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; display: none;"></div><div id="cboxSlideshow" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; display: none;"></div><div id="cboxClose" autocomplete="off" style="float: left;">close</div></div><div id="cboxMiddleRight" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; height: 306px;"></div></div><div style="clear: left;"><div id="cboxBottomLeft" autocomplete="off" style="float: left;"></div><div id="cboxBottomCenter" autocomplete="off" style="float: left; width: 550px;"></div><div id="cboxBottomRight" autocomplete="off" style="float: left;"></div></div></div><div style="position: absolute; width: 9999px; visibility: hidden; display: none;"></div></div>
  
  <span id="calBorder" style="position: absolute; left: 642px; top: 137px; width: 208px; border: 1pt solid rgb(0, 0, 0); padding: 0px; cursor: move; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); z-index: 10000; visibility: hidden;"></span>
```

Comment: You are using **Colorbox - a jQuery lightbox**, 

Please visit [GitHub for Colorbox here](https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox), [click here to see examples](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/)

Comment: Click here to download code https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/archive/master.zip

Comment: thank you, but on my code it not works.. I don't want to use any other model instead my code.please if you know please send me jsfiddle included my code.pls

Answer (score 0):

You are using **Colorbox - a jQuery lightbox**

Please check below example :

```js
/*!
 Colorbox 1.6.4
 license: MIT
 http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox
*/
(function(t,e,i){function n(i,n,o){var r=e.createElement(i);return n&&(r.id=Z+n),o&&(r.style.cssText=o),t(r)}function o(){return i.innerHeight?i.innerHeight:t(i).height()}function r(e,i){i!==Object(i)&&(i={}),this.cache={},this.el=e,this.value=function(e){var n;return void 0===this.cache[e]&&(n=t(this.el).attr("data-cbox-"+e),void 0!==n?this.cache[e]=n:void 0!==i[e]?this.cache[e]=i[e]:void 0!==X[e]&&(this.cache[e]=X[e])),this.cache[e]},this.get=function(e){var i=this.value(e);return t.isFunction(i)?i.call(this.el,this):i}}function h(t){var e=W.length,i=(A+t)%e;return 0>i?e+i:i}function a(t,e){return Math.round((/%/.test(t)?("x"===e?E.width():o())/100:1)*parseInt(t,10))}function s(t,e){return t.get("photo")||t.get("photoRegex").test(e)}function l(t,e){return t.get("retinaUrl")&&i.devicePixelRatio>1?e.replace(t.get("photoRegex"),t.get("retinaSuffix")):e}function d(t){"contains"in x[0]&&!x[0].contains(t.target)&&t.target!==v[0]&&(t.stopPropagation(),x.focus())}function c(t){c.str!==t&&(x.add(v).removeClass(c.str).addClass(t),c.str=t)}function g(e){A=0,e&&e!==!1&&"nofollow"!==e?(W=t("."+te).filter(function(){var i=t.data(this,Y),n=new r(this,i);return n.get("rel")===e}),A=W.index(_.el),-1===A&&(W=W.add(_.el),A=W.length-1)):W=t(_.el)}function u(i){t(e).trigger(i),ae.triggerHandler(i)}function f(i){var o;if(!G){if(o=t(i).data(Y),_=new r(i,o),g(_.get("rel")),!U){U=$=!0,c(_.get("className")),x.css({visibility:"hidden",display:"block",opacity:""}),I=n(se,"LoadedContent","width:0; height:0; overflow:hidden; visibility:hidden"),b.css({width:"",height:""}).append(I),j=T.height()+k.height()+b.outerHeight(!0)-b.height(),D=C.width()+H.width()+b.outerWidth(!0)-b.width(),N=I.outerHeight(!0),z=I.outerWidth(!0);var h=a(_.get("initialWidth"),"x"),s=a(_.get("initialHeight"),"y"),l=_.get("maxWidth"),f=_.get("maxHeight");_.w=Math.max((l!==!1?Math.min(h,a(l,"x")):h)-z-D,0),_.h=Math.max((f!==!1?Math.min(s,a(f,"y")):s)-N-j,0),I.css({width:"",height:_.h}),J.position(),u(ee),_.get("onOpen"),O.add(F).hide(),x.focus(),_.get("trapFocus")&&e.addEventListener&&(e.addEventListener("focus",d,!0),ae.one(re,function(){e.removeEventListener("focus",d,!0)})),_.get("returnFocus")&&ae.one(re,function(){t(_.el).focus()})}var p=parseFloat(_.get("opacity"));v.css({opacity:p===p?p:"",cursor:_.get("overlayClose")?"pointer":"",visibility:"visible"}).show(),_.get("closeButton")?B.html(_.get("close")).appendTo(b):B.appendTo("<div/>"),w()}}function p(){x||(V=!1,E=t(i),x=n(se).attr({id:Y,"class":t.support.opacity===!1?Z+"IE":"",role:"dialog",tabindex:"-1"}).hide(),v=n(se,"Overlay").hide(),L=t([n(se,"LoadingOverlay")[0],n(se,"LoadingGraphic")[0]]),y=n(se,"Wrapper"),b=n(se,"Content").append(F=n(se,"Title"),R=n(se,"Current"),P=t('<button type="button"/>').attr({id:Z+"Previous"}),K=t('<button type="button"/>').attr({id:Z+"Next"}),S=t('<button type="button"/>').attr({id:Z+"Slideshow"}),L),B=t('<button type="button"/>').attr({id:Z+"Close"}),y.append(n(se).append(n(se,"TopLeft"),T=n(se,"TopCenter"),n(se,"TopRight")),n(se,!1,"clear:left").append(C=n(se,"MiddleLeft"),b,H=n(se,"MiddleRight")),n(se,!1,"clear:left").append(n(se,"BottomLeft"),k=n(se,"BottomCenter"),n(se,"BottomRight"))).find("div div").css({"float":"left"}),M=n(se,!1,"position:absolute; width:9999px; visibility:hidden; display:none; max-width:none;"),O=K.add(P).add(R).add(S)),e.body&&!x.parent().length&&t(e.body).append(v,x.append(y,M))}function m(){function i(t){t.which>1||t.shiftKey||t.altKey||t.metaKey||t.ctrlKey||(t.preventDefault(),f(this))}return x?(V||(V=!0,K.click(function(){J.next()}),P.click(function(){J.prev()}),B.click(function(){J.close()}),v.click(function(){_.get("overlayClose")&&J.close()}),t(e).bind("keydown."+Z,function(t){var e=t.keyCode;U&&_.get("escKey")&&27===e&&(t.preventDefault(),J.close()),U&&_.get("arrowKey")&&W[1]&&!t.altKey&&(37===e?(t.preventDefault(),P.click()):39===e&&(t.preventDefault(),K.click()))}),t.isFunction(t.fn.on)?t(e).on("click."+Z,"."+te,i):t("."+te).live("click."+Z,i)),!0):!1}function w(){var e,o,r,h=J.prep,d=++le;if($=!0,q=!1,u(he),u(ie),_.get("onLoad"),_.h=_.get("height")?a(_.get("height"),"y")-N-j:_.get("innerHeight")&&a(_.get("innerHeight"),"y"),_.w=_.get("width")?a(_.get("width"),"x")-z-D:_.get("innerWidth")&&a(_.get("innerWidth"),"x"),_.mw=_.w,_.mh=_.h,_.get("maxWidth")&&(_.mw=a(_.get("maxWidth"),"x")-z-D,_.mw=_.w&&_.w<_.mw?_.w:_.mw),_.get("maxHeight")&&(_.mh=a(_.get("maxHeight"),"y")-N-j,_.mh=_.h&&_.h<_.mh?_.h:_.mh),e=_.get("href"),Q=setTimeout(function(){L.show()},100),_.get("inline")){var c=t(e).eq(0);r=t("<div>").hide().insertBefore(c),ae.one(he,function(){r.replaceWith(c)}),h(c)}else _.get("iframe")?h(" "):_.get("html")?h(_.get("html")):s(_,e)?(e=l(_,e),q=_.get("createImg"),t(q).addClass(Z+"Photo").bind("error."+Z,function(){h(n(se,"Error").html(_.get("imgError")))}).one("load",function(){d===le&&setTimeout(function(){var e;_.get("retinaImage")&&i.devicePixelRatio>1&&(q.height=q.height/i.devicePixelRatio,q.width=q.width/i.devicePixelRatio),_.get("scalePhotos")&&(o=function(){q.height-=q.height*e,q.width-=q.width*e},_.mw&&q.width>_.mw&&(e=(q.width-_.mw)/q.width,o()),_.mh&&q.height>_.mh&&(e=(q.height-_.mh)/q.height,o())),_.h&&(q.style.marginTop=Math.max(_.mh-q.height,0)/2+"px"),W[1]&&(_.get("loop")||W[A+1])&&(q.style.cursor="pointer",t(q).bind("click."+Z,function(){J.next()})),q.style.width=q.width+"px",q.style.height=q.height+"px",h(q)},1)}),q.src=e):e&&M.load(e,_.get("data"),function(e,i){d===le&&h("error"===i?n(se,"Error").html(_.get("xhrError")):t(this).contents())})}var v,x,y,b,T,C,H,k,W,E,I,M,L,F,R,S,K,P,B,O,_,j,D,N,z,A,q,U,$,G,Q,J,V,X={html:!1,photo:!1,iframe:!1,inline:!1,transition:"elastic",speed:300,fadeOut:300,width:!1,initialWidth:"600",innerWidth:!1,maxWidth:!1,height:!1,initialHeight:"450",innerHeight:!1,maxHeight:!1,scalePhotos:!0,scrolling:!0,opacity:.9,preloading:!0,className:!1,overlayClose:!0,escKey:!0,arrowKey:!0,top:!1,bottom:!1,left:!1,right:!1,fixed:!1,data:void 0,closeButton:!0,fastIframe:!0,open:!1,reposition:!0,loop:!0,slideshow:!1,slideshowAuto:!0,slideshowSpeed:2500,slideshowStart:"start slideshow",slideshowStop:"stop slideshow",photoRegex:/\.(gif|png|jp(e|g|eg)|bmp|ico|webp|jxr|svg)((#|\?).*)?$/i,retinaImage:!1,retinaUrl:!1,retinaSuffix:"@2x.$1",current:"image {current} of {total}",previous:"previous",next:"next",close:"close",xhrError:"This content failed to load.",imgError:"This image failed to load.",returnFocus:!0,trapFocus:!0,onOpen:!1,onLoad:!1,onComplete:!1,onCleanup:!1,onClosed:!1,rel:function(){return this.rel},href:function(){return t(this).attr("href")},title:function(){return this.title},createImg:function(){var e=new Image,i=t(this).data("cbox-img-attrs");return"object"==typeof i&&t.each(i,function(t,i){e[t]=i}),e},createIframe:function(){var i=e.createElement("iframe"),n=t(this).data("cbox-iframe-attrs");return"object"==typeof n&&t.each(n,function(t,e){i[t]=e}),"frameBorder"in i&&(i.frameBorder=0),"allowTransparency"in i&&(i.allowTransparency="true"),i.name=(new Date).getTime(),i.allowFullscreen=!0,i}},Y="colorbox",Z="cbox",te=Z+"Element",ee=Z+"_open",ie=Z+"_load",ne=Z+"_complete",oe=Z+"_cleanup",re=Z+"_closed",he=Z+"_purge",ae=t("<a/>"),se="div",le=0,de={},ce=function(){function t(){clearTimeout(h)}function e(){(_.get("loop")||W[A+1])&&(t(),h=setTimeout(J.next,_.get("slideshowSpeed")))}function i(){S.html(_.get("slideshowStop")).unbind(s).one(s,n),ae.bind(ne,e).bind(ie,t),x.removeClass(a+"off").addClass(a+"on")}function n(){t(),ae.unbind(ne,e).unbind(ie,t),S.html(_.get("slideshowStart")).unbind(s).one(s,function(){J.next(),i()}),x.removeClass(a+"on").addClass(a+"off")}function o(){r=!1,S.hide(),t(),ae.unbind(ne,e).unbind(ie,t),x.removeClass(a+"off "+a+"on")}var r,h,a=Z+"Slideshow_",s="click."+Z;return function(){r?_.get("slideshow")||(ae.unbind(oe,o),o()):_.get("slideshow")&&W[1]&&(r=!0,ae.one(oe,o),_.get("slideshowAuto")?i():n(),S.show())}}();t[Y]||(t(p),J=t.fn[Y]=t[Y]=function(e,i){var n,o=this;return e=e||{},t.isFunction(o)&&(o=t("<a/>"),e.open=!0),o[0]?(p(),m()&&(i&&(e.onComplete=i),o.each(function(){var i=t.data(this,Y)||{};t.data(this,Y,t.extend(i,e))}).addClass(te),n=new r(o[0],e),n.get("open")&&f(o[0])),o):o},J.position=function(e,i){function n(){T[0].style.width=k[0].style.width=b[0].style.width=parseInt(x[0].style.width,10)-D+"px",b[0].style.height=C[0].style.height=H[0].style.height=parseInt(x[0].style.height,10)-j+"px"}var r,h,s,l=0,d=0,c=x.offset();if(E.unbind("resize."+Z),x.css({top:-9e4,left:-9e4}),h=E.scrollTop(),s=E.scrollLeft(),_.get("fixed")?(c.top-=h,c.left-=s,x.css({position:"fixed"})):(l=h,d=s,x.css({position:"absolute"})),d+=_.get("right")!==!1?Math.max(E.width()-_.w-z-D-a(_.get("right"),"x"),0):_.get("left")!==!1?a(_.get("left"),"x"):Math.round(Math.max(E.width()-_.w-z-D,0)/2),l+=_.get("bottom")!==!1?Math.max(o()-_.h-N-j-a(_.get("bottom"),"y"),0):_.get("top")!==!1?a(_.get("top"),"y"):Math.round(Math.max(o()-_.h-N-j,0)/2),x.css({top:c.top,left:c.left,visibility:"visible"}),y[0].style.width=y[0].style.height="9999px",r={width:_.w+z+D,height:_.h+N+j,top:l,left:d},e){var g=0;t.each(r,function(t){return r[t]!==de[t]?(g=e,void 0):void 0}),e=g}de=r,e||x.css(r),x.dequeue().animate(r,{duration:e||0,complete:function(){n(),$=!1,y[0].style.width=_.w+z+D+"px",y[0].style.height=_.h+N+j+"px",_.get("reposition")&&setTimeout(function(){E.bind("resize."+Z,J.position)},1),t.isFunction(i)&&i()},step:n})},J.resize=function(t){var e;U&&(t=t||{},t.width&&(_.w=a(t.width,"x")-z-D),t.innerWidth&&(_.w=a(t.innerWidth,"x")),I.css({width:_.w}),t.height&&(_.h=a(t.height,"y")-N-j),t.innerHeight&&(_.h=a(t.innerHeight,"y")),t.innerHeight||t.height||(e=I.scrollTop(),I.css({height:"auto"}),_.h=I.height()),I.css({height:_.h}),e&&I.scrollTop(e),J.position("none"===_.get("transition")?0:_.get("speed")))},J.prep=function(i){function o(){return _.w=_.w||I.width(),_.w=_.mw&&_.mw<_.w?_.mw:_.w,_.w}function a(){return _.h=_.h||I.height(),_.h=_.mh&&_.mh<_.h?_.mh:_.h,_.h}if(U){var d,g="none"===_.get("transition")?0:_.get("speed");I.remove(),I=n(se,"LoadedContent").append(i),I.hide().appendTo(M.show()).css({width:o(),overflow:_.get("scrolling")?"auto":"hidden"}).css({height:a()}).prependTo(b),M.hide(),t(q).css({"float":"none"}),c(_.get("className")),d=function(){function i(){t.support.opacity===!1&&x[0].style.removeAttribute("filter")}var n,o,a=W.length;U&&(o=function(){clearTimeout(Q),L.hide(),u(ne),_.get("onComplete")},F.html(_.get("title")).show(),I.show(),a>1?("string"==typeof _.get("current")&&R.html(_.get("current").replace("{current}",A+1).replace("{total}",a)).show(),K[_.get("loop")||a-1>A?"show":"hide"]().html(_.get("next")),P[_.get("loop")||A?"show":"hide"]().html(_.get("previous")),ce(),_.get("preloading")&&t.each([h(-1),h(1)],function(){var i,n=W[this],o=new r(n,t.data(n,Y)),h=o.get("href");h&&s(o,h)&&(h=l(o,h),i=e.createElement("img"),i.src=h)})):O.hide(),_.get("iframe")?(n=_.get("createIframe"),_.get("scrolling")||(n.scrolling="no"),t(n).attr({src:_.get("href"),"class":Z+"Iframe"}).one("load",o).appendTo(I),ae.one(he,function(){n.src="//about:blank"}),_.get("fastIframe")&&t(n).trigger("load")):o(),"fade"===_.get("transition")?x.fadeTo(g,1,i):i())},"fade"===_.get("transition")?x.fadeTo(g,0,function(){J.position(0,d)}):J.position(g,d)}},J.next=function(){!$&&W[1]&&(_.get("loop")||W[A+1])&&(A=h(1),f(W[A]))},J.prev=function(){!$&&W[1]&&(_.get("loop")||A)&&(A=h(-1),f(W[A]))},J.close=function(){U&&!G&&(G=!0,U=!1,u(oe),_.get("onCleanup"),E.unbind("."+Z),v.fadeTo(_.get("fadeOut")||0,0),x.stop().fadeTo(_.get("fadeOut")||0,0,function(){x.hide(),v.hide(),u(he),I.remove(),setTimeout(function(){G=!1,u(re),_.get("onClosed")},1)}))},J.remove=function(){x&&(x.stop(),t[Y].close(),x.stop(!1,!0).remove(),v.remove(),G=!1,x=null,t("."+te).removeData(Y).removeClass(te),t(e).unbind("click."+Z).unbind("keydown."+Z))},J.element=function(){return t(_.el)},J.settings=X)})(jQuery,document,window);


$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".inline").colorbox({ inline: true, width: "50%" });
});
```

```css
/*
    Colorbox Core Style:
    The following CSS is consistent between example themes and should not be altered.
*/
#colorbox, #cboxOverlay, #cboxWrapper{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:9999; overflow:hidden; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);}
#cboxWrapper {max-width:none;}
#cboxOverlay{position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%;}
#cboxMiddleLeft, #cboxBottomLeft{clear:left;}
#cboxContent{position:relative;}
#cboxLoadedContent{overflow:auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;}
#cboxTitle{margin:0;}
#cboxLoadingOverlay, #cboxLoadingGraphic{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;}
#cboxPrevious, #cboxNext, #cboxClose, #cboxSlideshow{cursor:pointer;}
.cboxPhoto{float:left; margin:auto; border:0; display:block; max-width:none; -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;}
.cboxIframe{width:100%; height:100%; display:block; border:0; padding:0; margin:0;}
#colorbox, #cboxContent, #cboxLoadedContent{box-sizing:content-box; -moz-box-sizing:content-box; -webkit-box-sizing:content-box;}

/* 
    User Style:
    Change the following styles to modify the appearance of Colorbox.  They are
    ordered & tabbed in a way that represents the nesting of the generated HTML.
*/
#cboxOverlay{background:url(http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/images/overlay.png) repeat 0 0; opacity: 0.9; filter: alpha(opacity = 90);}
#colorbox{outline:0;}
    #cboxTopLeft{width:21px; height:21px; background:url(http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/images/controls.png) no-repeat -101px 0;}
    #cboxTopRight{width:21px; height:21px; background:url(http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/images/controls.png) no-repeat -130px 0;}
    #cboxBottomLeft{width:21px; height:21px; background:url(http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/images/controls.png) no-repeat -101px -29px;}
    #cboxBottomRight{width:21px; height:21px; background:url(http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/images/controls.png) no-repeat -130px -29px;}
    #cboxMiddleLeft{width:21px; background:url(http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/images/controls.png) left top repeat-y;}
    #cboxMiddleRight{width:21px; background:url(http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/images/controls.png) right top repeat-y;}
    #cboxTopCenter{height:21px; background:url(http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/images/border.png) 0 0 repeat-x;}
    #cboxBottomCenter{height:21px; background:url(http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/images/border.png) 0 -29px repeat-x;}
    #cboxContent{background:#fff; overflow:hidden;}
        .cboxIframe{background:#fff;}
        #cboxError{padding:50px; border:1px solid #ccc;}
        #cboxLoadedContent{margin-bottom:28px;}
        #cboxTitle{position:absolute; bottom:4px; left:0; text-align:center; width:100%; color:#949494;}
        #cboxCurrent{position:absolute; bottom:4px; left:58px; color:#949494;}
        #cboxLoadingOverlay{background:url(http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/images/loading_background.png) no-repeat center center;}
        #cboxLoadingGraphic{background:url(http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/images/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;}

        /* these elements are buttons, and may need to have additional styles reset to avoid unwanted base styles */
        #cboxPrevious, #cboxNext, #cboxSlideshow, #cboxClose {border:0; padding:0; margin:0; overflow:visible; width:auto; background:none; }
        
        /* avoid outlines on :active (mouseclick), but preserve outlines on :focus (tabbed navigating) */
        #cboxPrevious:active, #cboxNext:active, #cboxSlideshow:active, #cboxClose:active {outline:0;}

        #cboxSlideshow{position:absolute; bottom:4px; right:30px; color:#0092ef;}
        #cboxPrevious{position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0; background:url(http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/images/controls.png) no-repeat -75px 0; width:25px; height:25px; text-indent:-9999px;}
        #cboxPrevious:hover{background-position:-75px -25px;}
        #cboxNext{position:absolute; bottom:0; left:27px; background:url(http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/images/controls.png) no-repeat -50px 0; width:25px; height:25px; text-indent:-9999px;}
        #cboxNext:hover{background-position:-50px -25px;}
        #cboxClose{position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0; background:url(http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/images/controls.png) no-repeat -25px 0; width:25px; height:25px; text-indent:-9999px;}
        #cboxClose:hover{background-position:-25px -25px;}

/*
  The following fixes a problem where IE7 and IE8 replace a PNG's alpha transparency with a black fill
  when an alpha filter (opacity change) is set on the element or ancestor element.  This style is not applied to or needed in IE9.
  See: http://jacklmoore.com/notes/ie-transparency-problems/
*/
.cboxIE #cboxTopLeft,
.cboxIE #cboxTopCenter,
.cboxIE #cboxTopRight,
.cboxIE #cboxBottomLeft,
.cboxIE #cboxBottomCenter,
.cboxIE #cboxBottomRight,
.cboxIE #cboxMiddleLeft,
.cboxIE #cboxMiddleRight {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><a class='inline' href="#inline_content">Click to open model </a></p>

<!-- This contains the hidden content for inline calls -->
<div style='display:none'>
    <div id='inline_content' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
        <h3 class="page-title_fg">Forget Password</h3>
        <form style="padding: 15px;">
            <label>User Name*</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="fuserName" name="fuserName" class="box" maxlength="15" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off"><br>
            <label>Date of Birth*</label> <input type="text" id="fdob" name="fdob" class="box" maxlength="15" autofocus="autofocus" onclick="clkdate('fdob');" readonly="readonly" autocomplete="off"><br>
            <label>Email id*</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="femailId" name="femailId" class="box" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off"><br>
            <!-- <input type="button" value="Get Password" id="forget_pwd_submit_btn" class="login_btn"/>
            <input type="button" value="Reset" id="forget_pwd_reset_btn" class="login_btn"/> -->
            <button type="button" value="Get Password" id="forget_pwd_submit_btn" autocomplete="off">Get Password</button>
            <button type="button" value="Reset" id="forget_pwd_reset_btn" autocomplete="off">Reset</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is an CodePen example](https://codepen.io/saAction/pen/XxYoKM)

Please visit [GitHub for Colorbox here](https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox) for more detail

Comment: this is my jsfiddle how I add functions in Jquery in this jsfiddle.. https://jsfiddle.net/techWorld/yfdk1zjs/1/